# Accessing menustrip of other process

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, automated-tests

Im working on automating the behavious of a scientific measurement program in C#.

The program does have a .net API, but the developers of the program  havent included all necessary commands eg. they havent included a simple "save as" command that i need for saving the measureing data.

[image]

Is there a way to operate the menu strip of the application and e.g. press the save as  button.

I start the program from my own application by means of Process.Start();

Comment: Automating the UI is best performed through [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution - copy destination path to the clipboard, then use e.g. `SendKeys.SendWait()` to send the following keys to your target application (with sufficient pauses between them) Ctrl+S `"^s"`, Ctrl+V `"^v"`, Enter `"{ENTER}"`.

It's also a good idea to verify the folder exists, and the file does not, otherwise the saving will obviously fail, or overwrite confirmation will popup.

P.S. But before doing that, use e.g. .NET Reflector to ensure their .NET API doesn't have the save functionality: there're many cases where the SendKeys approach will fail.